# Bootstrap isn't working on Angular 11 upon adding to the project

Tags: angular, user-interface, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular11

I am trying to use bootstrap 4.6 on angular 11, I have done following steps.

1. It was installed and listed under the package as `"bootstrap": "^4.6.0"`
2. Listed bootstrap inside `angular.json` under `styles`:

   ```
   "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
             ],
   ```

   **Still its not loading bootstrap**
3. Tried changing directory as in `./node_modules` or `../node_modules` or `node_modules` nothing works.
4. used import bootstrap in style file it works fine but why its not working when I declared it in `angular.json`.

Please let me know what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can define different named build configurations on your angular.json, are you including the "styles" inside "build" and "serve" sections? Also can you see the physical css file on your filesystem?

Comment: yes everything is already their as you have mentioned declared in style present in build and physical css is their that's why style.css is able to run it